# Metric tensor under coordinate transformation x to y(x)

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

Say I have a metric representation $g_{\mu\nu}$ in a coordinate system $x$ and I want to find the representation of the metric in a new set of coordinates $y = y(x)$.  I know how to do this if you are given $x(y)$, as in [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/16681/metric-tensor-of-coordinate-transformation).

$g_{\mu' \nu'} = \frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial y^{\mu'}} \frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial y^{\nu'}} g_{\mu \nu}$ --------  $(1)$

But what if I'm only given $y=y(x)$, and it's tricky to figure out $x=x(y)$?  Is there a method that uses partial derivatives $\frac{\partial y^{\mu'}}{\partial x^{\mu}}$ instead?  Or is $(1)$ the only way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The $\partial x^\mu/\partial y^{\mu'}$ are just the components of the Jacobian matrix, and the Jacobian of an inverse transformation is equal to the inverse of the original Jacobian.  Find the Jacobian matrix that underlies $y = y(x)$, invert it, and you should have the correct components.

Comment: it was a hefty undertaking, but i think i managed it ok.  thanks for the advice.